# ngx-bootstrap when modal height is dynamic scroll is not coming

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular5, ngx-bootstrap

I want to change the height of `modal` dynamically whenever the content inside the `modal` is expanding or collapsing. The scenario is I have a `collapsible` aria inside the modal which expands when `view answer` button gets clicked. Now while first time loading if content height of `modal` needs scroll then even after `view answer` button click everything works fine. But if initial height does not need a scroll that time even after expanding the content scroll is not coming which blocks user to perform further actions.

Screens:
Before expanding [screen before clicking view answer button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zv1c4.png)
After expanding [screen after clicking view answer button. Here I need scroll otherwise user will get blocked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cYuG.png)

Code:

```html
<ng-template #template>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">New question</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p class="text-left padding-b-10 border-b-q" [innerHTML]="'Q. ' + questions[nextQuestionIndex].question"></p>
        <p class="text-left padding-b-10 border-b-q" (click)="handleOptionClick(i)" *ngFor="let option of questions[nextQuestionIndex].options; let i = index">
            {{i + '. '}}<span [innerHTML]="option" [ngClass]="{'text-success': (questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer === i) && optionValidationArr[i],'text-danger': (questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer !== i) && optionValidationArr[i]}"></span><span class="float-right"
                [ngClass]="{'text-success': (questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer === i) && optionValidationArr[i]}" *ngIf="(questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer === i) && optionValidationArr[i]">You are right</span><span class="float-right" [ngClass]="{'text-danger': (questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer !== i) && optionValidationArr[i]}"
                *ngIf="(questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer !== i) && optionValidationArr[i]">Please try again</span>
        </p>
        <div class="container">
            <p>
                <a class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-toggle="collapse" href="#multiCollapseExample1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="multiCollapseExample1">View answer</a>
            </p>
            <p class="text-danger">This will reduce your score please try your best before viewing the answer</p>
            <div class="collapse multi-collapse" id="multiCollapseExample1">
                <div class="card card-body">
                    Correct answer: <span class="text-success">{{questions[nextQuestionIndex].answer}}</span><br> Explaination: <span></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-success progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="progress.correctPer" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress.correctPer" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{(progress.correctPer ? (progress.correctPer + '%'):'')}}</div>
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger progress-bar-animated progress-bar-striped" role="progressbar" [style.width.%]="progress.wrongPer" [attr.aria-valuenow]="progress.wrongPer" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{{(progress.wrongPer ? (progress.wrongPer+'%'):'')}}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" (click)="closeModal()">End practice</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" (click)="getNextQuestion(template, resultTemplate)">{{(((questionArrLen-1) !== nextQuestionIndex) ? "Next question" : "View result")}}</button>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about do it like this?

Add a class on modal-body and set height and overflow.

```
<div class="modal-body question-modal-body">
</div>

.question-modal-body {
    max-height: 150px; // set the height which the answer is not shown
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: My buttons are in footer part of the modal so even after scrolling body I am not able to see the buttons

Answer (score 0):

Looks so late to the party, just hope my answer helps someone later. After seeing your screenshot, I suggest having a "Modal scrollable content" approach for your UI. So, only the "content" will expand and push the modal height to the maximum of the screen height ( not over screen height ). So, the modal header and footer will always keep visible, and the content area is scrollable.

Please check the demo on the following Codepen I have made: https://codesandbox.io/s/ngx-boostrap-scrollable-modal-69jox.

It is using:

- bootstrap@4.6.1 ( as seen in `index.html` )
- ngx-bootstrap@7.1.2

The trick is to have a special class added to the modal when doing `modalService.show()`. You can see it at `/src/app/app.component.ts`

```
  openModal(template: TemplateRef<any>) {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(template, {
      class: "modal-dialog-centered modal-dialog-scrollable"
    });
  }
```

The class name I have mentioned earlier was `modal-dialog-scrollable`. About `modal-dialog-centered` is just my personal preference to have the dialog always get centered.

More about "Modal option" used above can be found at the documentation here: https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/old/5.6.0/#/modals#modal-options

Hope this answer helps someone. Thanks :)